# Is this the right approach to handle build context related task

Tags: flutter, memory-leaks, overlay, loading

Following is code for custom UI helper which does nothing more than add a loading overlay entry to current context and display a about dialogue when clicked on a button.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'app_settings.dart' as settings;

class UiHelper {
  static OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;

  static triggerLoadingOverlay() {
    _overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height,
        width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.25),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: UnconstrainedBox(
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
                strokeWidth: 2.0,
                strokeCap: StrokeCap.round,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
    // ADD OVERLAY IN THE WIDGET TREE
    _getCurrentOverlayState()!.insert(_overlayEntry!);
  }

  static detachLoadingOverlay() {
    _overlayEntry?.remove();
    _overlayEntry = null;
  }

  static OverlayState? _getCurrentOverlayState() {
    return settings.navigatorKey.currentState?.overlay;
  }

  static BuildContext? _getCurrentContext() {
    return settings.navigatorKey.currentState?.context;
  }

  static showDialogue() {
    showAboutDialog(context: _getCurrentContext()!, children: [
      const Text("About"),
    ]);
  }
}
```

**My question**: Is this going to effect my app's performance like memory leaks or something like that which could cause me trouble in the later development stage?